# Pulling in product details using custom HTML in Google Tag Manager

Tags: e-commerce, product, google-tag-manager

I am using custom HTML on Google Tag Manager to set up event tracking for an e-commerce website. However, I also want it to pull in product details, so I know I need to add to this code to capture the variable information. I am seeing the information in the DataLayer in the form of an array. Can I get guidance on how to pull that in?[screenshot of data in GTM 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3OMk.jpg)[screenshot of data in GTM 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eatVt.jpg)

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
   var vendor = window.vendor || [];
   vendor.track("Added To Cart", {{Add to Cart}});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your datalayer looks like this

[image]

Then yes. You can retrieve this data from `DataLayer Variable`

[image]

Just create like this setting.

Then you can see it from the preview.

[image]

---

Just be careful for what your vendor's tracking code might not use the same format or structure as the Google's ecommerce datalayer.

Comment: Interesting. I created a dlv variable, but I think my question is how do I add it into the tracking script? If I named the variable "Add to Cart - Variable 2" do I add it in something along the lines of the below?

<script type = "text/javascript">
   var vendor = window.vendor || [];
   var item = {Add to Cart - Variable 2[0]}
   vendor.track("Added To Cart", {{Add to Cart}});
</script>

Comment: Something like {{Add to Cart - Variable 2}}[0]. If you want to get first item in the array